# What does “Yarhamukallah” mean?

Tags: practical-islam, arabic

When someone sneezes, we often say “Yarhamukallah”. What does the “Yarhamukallah” actually means?

Is there any restrictions to not to say “Yarhamukallah” to someone **or** we always should answer this to sneezing for everyone? What is the proper way?

Comment: Some say it's [sufficiency duty](https://ar.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%81%D8%B1%D8%B6_%D9%83%D9%81%D8%A7%D9%8A%D8%A9), check this [arabic source](https://www.ahlalhdeeth.com/vb/showthread.php?t=30479) for details. Meaning if someone said "Yarhamukallah" to the person who sneezed, the rest of us don't have to say.

Answer (score 3):

Yarhamuk Allah يرحمك الله  means **May Allah have Mercy on you**, Yarham is from Raham (mercy).

When someone sneezes they should says "Al Hamdulilah" and when you witness this should you say "Yarhamuk Allah".

> Abu Huraira reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying:
>
> Six are the rights of a Muslim over another Muslim. It was said to
>   him: Allah's Messenger, what are these? Thereupon he said: When you
>   meet him, offer him greetings;when he invites you to a feast accept
>   it. when he seeks your council give him, and when he sneezes and
>   says:" All praise is due to Allah," you say Yarhamuk Allah (may Allah
>   show mercy to you) ; and when he fails ill visit him; and when he dies
>   follow his bier.
>
> https://sunnah.com/muslim/39/6